# 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'validate'

Tags: python, django, django-managers

My usual registration and login validators stopped working and I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why.

This is the error:
AttributeError at /register
'UserManager' object has no attribute 'validate'

Models.py

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def validate(self, postData):
        errors = {}
        if len(postData['first_name']) < 3:
            errors['first_name'] = 'First Name must be at least 2 characters'
        if len(postData['last_name']) < 3:
            errors['last_name'] = 'Last Name must be at least 2 characters'
        
        EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')
        if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(postData['email']):
            errors['email'] = "Invalid email address!"
        email_check=User.objects.filter(email=postData['email'])
        if email_check:
            errors['email'] = ("Email address already taken!")

        if len(postData['password']) < 8 :
            errors['password'] = 'Password must be at least 8 characters'
        if postData['password'] != postData['confirm_password']:
            errors['password'] = 'Passwords do not match'
        return errors

views.py

    def register(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return redirect('/')
    errors = User.objects.validate(request.POST)
    if errors:
        for e in errors.values():
            messages.error(request, e)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        new_user = User.objects.register(request.POST)
        request.session['user_id'] = new_user.id
        return redirect('/profile')
```

Here is my User model, thanks!

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Can you show your user model?

Comment: Why do you perform this validation in the _manager_? There are better places to do validation 1) _[Form classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/)_ . 2) The models various `clean`, etc. methods.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem I added my user model, thanks!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, this is just how I was taught but I'd love to do it a cleaner way in the future!